# How to separate the result of addition of string with comma in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to assign multiple string values to a variable.
For example:

```
@default_mail = "sid@mail.com"

@mail = "me@mail.com"
```

And then I am adding both of these variables and assigning to a new variable. May be this not a very efficient way of doing it:

```
 @reciever = @default_mail + @mail
```

This gives me.

"sid@mail.comme@mail.com"

But I want this to be an array. How do I do that?

Comment: Your question is unclear. In the title, you are asking how to concatenate strings with a comma in between, in your question, you ask about arrays. Strings and arrays are completely different things. Which of the two is it? What do you mean by "I want this to be an array"? What does "this" mean in that sentence? Do you want to have the string you showed in an array? Do you want to have string with a comma in an array? Something else? Can you provide your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you want to receive this:

```
@receiver = [@default_mail, @mail]
```

Comment: Yes . So this is how it's done? Mentioning the variables inside the array itself.

Comment: You can just write it as `a = 1;  b = 2;  c = [a, b]`

Comment: @IgorPavlov: Just for fun, you can omit the brackets : `a = 1; b = 2; c = a, b` or even `c = a = 1, b = 2`

Comment: @user3576036 `[...]` is an [array literal](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Arrays), not the array itself. It creates a new array containing the given objects.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you this way, that your receivers array should contain the default mail in any case.

```
@default_mail = "sid@mail.com"

@receiver = [@default_mail]
# => ["sid@mail.com"]
```

Now you could add as many additional receiver addresses as you want.

```
@mail = "me@mail.com"
@receiver << @mail
# => ["sid@mail.com", "me@mail.com"]
```

If each receiver should receive one mail only and your addresses are not unique ...

```
@receiver << @mail
# => ["sid@mail.com", "me@mail.com", "me@mail.com"]
```

... so make they unique:

```
@receiver.uniq
# => ["sid@mail.com", "me@mail.com"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `join` on array of strings:

```
@reciever = [@default_mail, @mail].join(', ')
```

This gives `"sid@mail.com, me@mail.com"`

Comment: I think OP wants an array, not a string.

Comment: It's unclear. The title of the question, the code of the question, and the bulk of the question text are about string concatenation; there is only a single mention of arrays at the very end: "I want this to be an array", but with no indication of what "this" is supposed to be.